# LinkedIn API: Sudden Permission errors for adCampaignsV2

Tags: linkedin-api

We (my work) have been fetching campaign analytics for our Live campaigns through the LinkedIn API for over a year.

Suddenly since mid-October we are getting Permissions errors. We have seemingly all the required permissions including r_ads, r_ads_reporting but still getting errors.

Nothing has changed that I can see. We have an up to date token since today.

We have:  Marketing Developer Platform • Development tier

Errors include:
Not enough permissions to access: GET-statuses /adCampaignsV2
Not enough permissions to access: GET-analytics /adAnalyticsV2

Comment: To answer my own question (Old to New Permissions Mapping) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/marketing-permissions-migration?context=linkedin/marketing/context

r_ad_campaigns replaced by r_ads and r_ads_reporting in the fetch token scope request